# Java time measurement incorrect

Tags: java, time, lejos-nxj

I have a java code that runs an endless loop, over and over again, and under certain conditions, I want to insert an additional step / function call into the loop.

I defined these variables outside of the loop:

```
static boolean wait_activate = false; 
static long wait_tmr = -1; 
static int wait_delay = 6;
```

Then, in my endless loop, when I want to enable the additional code:

```
if (some-condition) { 
    wait_activate = true; 
    System.out.println("activate"); 
    wait_tmr = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L); 
}
```

And at the beginning of the loop, I have two checks to insert the additional code:

```
if (wait_activate && (wait_tmr + wait_delay) < (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L)) {
    // if wait period isn't over
    do_additional_stuff(); 
}

if (wait_activate && (wait_tmr + wait_delay) > (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L)) {
    // wait time is over: 
    System.out.println("Reset time: " + wait_delay); 
    System.out.println("Stored time: " + wait_tmr); 
    System.out.println("Current time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L)); 
    wait_activate = false; 
    wait_tmr = -1; 
}
```

Now, the time values are all in seconds / unixtime. (currentTimeMillis / 1000 = seconds). `wait_delay` is 6. That would mean, the two `println`s should only be executed about 6 seconds after activating (with `wait_activate = true`).

However, the output is this:

```
activate
Reset time: 6
Stored time: 946685043
Current time: 946685045
```

I don't understand why. It should wait 6 seconds, according to `wait_delay`. However, the difference between the stored time and the current time is only 2 seconds. Even if I increase the wait_delay. Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug in Java or in the weird JRE version I (have to) use (running this on LeJOS 0.9.0-beta on a LEGO EV3)?

Am I making a complete "beginner mistake" and just don't see it? Or is something else broken there?

Comment: Just wondering, 946685045 is Saturday, January 1, 2000 12:04:05 AM. Is your computer clock turned this far back (or is the a very old question ;-) ?

Comment: This code runs in LeJOS on a LEGO EV3 system - an embedded system without continuous power supply and with no need for the current date / time, so, this code output is probably from 4:05 minutes after starting the device and it doesn't have (or need) an RTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with comparison operators, the first if condition should have > instead of <, while the second if condition should contain < instead of >. You may also turn the second "if" condition into an "else" of first "if" condition to avoid any further confusion.

Comment: Such a stupid mistake ... thanks for pointing that out. Now it works like it should. I didn't even think of that being the problem because it worked for 2-3 seconds. I guess that loop run just took that many seconds and it was immediately reset the next time.

Answer (score 0):

You may not want below assignment to happen over & over inside your endless loop while the wait_activate is ON. Maybe wrapping this assignment in right if condition will help.

wait_tmr = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);

Comment: Sorry, my question was a bit unclear there. There already is a (working) condition, this assignment only runs once and "activate" is only printed once.

Comment: Well, then it looks like the problem is with comparison operators, the first if condition should have > instead of <, while the second if condition should contain < instead of >.

Comment: By the way, you can convert the second "if" into the "else" of first "if" condition.